# Express memory leak

Tags: node.js, express, memory-leaks, out-of-memory

More code + info at : https://github.com/expressjs/express/issues/3817

I have a system that parses some data from files, and then send it to an Express API via a POST.

The size of the data is less than 1Mb.

I send around 7 requests per second (7 files parsed per second) to my api, here is the API code :

```
api.post('/data', async (req, res) => {
    let data = req.body.data;

    if (data) {
        log.info('Saving data : ' + data.filePath);

        let newData = await saveData(data);
        log.info('Finished saving data : ' + data.filePath);
        res.status(201).json(newData._id);
    }
    else
        res.status(400).end();
});
```

The saveData function :

```
async function saveData(d) {
    let x = await OtherData.findOneAndUpdate(...);
    //some processing...
    return Data.findByIdAndUpdate(d._id, d, {new: true, upsert: true});
}
```

If I check the output of the api with the logs, it's pretty instant I see both lines one after each other. Also, as soon as I stop sending data, I stop seeing the logs ouput, so there is not delay nor stacking of requests, it can definitely handle 7requests/s (I think).

I tried with the chrome debugger, this is what I get :

[image]

The size just keeps growing pretty fast, until reaching the max and then shutting down the server. Also, once I stop sending data, it doesn't free the memory right after, I need to wait for minutes.

If you have any idea on what's up or any hints on how to track this down more efficiently, that's be great.

Thanks

Update:

- Node v10.14
- Mongo v4.0.4
- Mongoose v5.3.13
- Express v4.16.4

**Edit**

I stripped down the `saveData` function and put everything inline inside the `api.post` function, still have the same issue.

Now the code looks like this :

```
api.post('/data', async (req, res) => {
    let data = req.body.data;

    if (data) {
        log.info('Saving data : ' + data.filePath);

        let x = await OtherData.findOneAndUpdate(...);
        //some processing...
        let newData = await Data.findByIdAndUpdate(data._id, data, {new: true, upsert: true});
        log.info('Finished saving data : ' + data.filePath);
        res.status(201).json(newData._id);
    }
    else
        res.status(400).end();
});
```

**Update 2**

I totally removed the mongoose related code - I'm literally just receiving the data and returning a string 'received', still the memory just grows.

Might be related to : https://github.com/expressjs/express/issues/3413

Comment: Check if there are any references left to saveData function argument even after returning from the function that could be the possibility. Because of this GC is not able to clean up the data in the memory.

Comment: @Sanket it doesn't seem that there are references to saveData nor its arguments...I'm using ``let`` keyword everywhere so at the end of the function it should be destroyed right?

Comment: Shouldn't `res.status(201).end(newData._id);` be `res.status(201).send(newData._id);` ?  https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.end

Comment: I think its important to know/look at what versions of express/mongoose/node you're using.

Comment: @CodyG. I have added versions, also I just tested with ``.end`` but I had ``.json`` before, didn't affect anything.

Comment: Well that was an interesting read

Comment: I wonder if you can destroy the express / http server every so often or something and see if it gets GC'd

Comment: @HRK44 did you find any solution or any workaround for the leak?

Comment: @Tirolel I've just increased the node app memory and limited my calls, couldn't find why it was behaving like this